# Arduino Temperature Sensor

Tags: arduino-uno, temperature-sensor

We are doing a project and we need to build a thermo sensor and read the voltage and the temperature but we also have to have the temperature correspond to LEDs that will give a blue for cold green for mild and red for hot we are using a DS18b20 thermo sensor.

How should we write the code or where could we find code that would work for this purpose?

We both have a very surface level understanding of code at the moment, however our time constraints have made learning it difficult.

Comment: Please show us the code you've written so far.

Comment: What is the reason for your time constraint? Is this a school project? Is it for CS? What resources do you have for the class? Do you understand how to set up the hardware, and just need help with the software? What's your background?

Answer (score 1):

This forum isn't great for detailed solutions to vague problems. If you don't have much experience with programming, you'll have a lot to figure out. It will take you a while (realistically probably a couple of weeks if you work at it every day, and have a knack for it, assuming you're starting from scratch.)

The first step is to define your problem. It sounds like you want to build a project that uses colored LEDs to indicate the measured temperature in different ranges.

So lets say you want:

```
Temp <10°C light Blue LED
Temp 10°C - 30°C light green LED
temp >30°C light red LED.
```

Break the problem into bite-sized pieces and solve them one at a time.

Pick an Arduino model. Install the IDE. Run a sketch that will blink the built-in LED. Then do a google search on "Arduino Blink without delay" and rewrite your blink code to not use the `delay()` function. Forget the `delay()` function exists and never use it again, since it will usually get in the way of what you need to do.

Then figure out how to wire separate LEDs (including current limiting resistors) to 3 separate pins. Make your code blink all 3 LEDs at the same time by toggling the appropriate pins' output states.

Modify your app to blink first one LED, the 2nd, and then the third. Now get tricky and modify your app to blink the first LED on and off once a second, the next LED once every 1/3 of a second, and the fourth LED to blink once every 1/4 second, all at the same time. (That will force you to really understand how to do timing without delay.)

Now look up a sample project that uses your temp sensor. (Try [**this one I found**](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/TheGadgetBoy/ds18b20-digital-temperature-sensor-and-arduino-9cc806), for example) Run that and get it to send the temp to your serial port once every few seconds. (again not using `delay()`.)

Now write a loop that reads the temp sensor, decides which range the temp is in, and lights the appropriate LED based on those ranges. Note that you may only be able to read the temp every 2 seconds or so (the DHT22 and DHT11 temp sensors I've used have that limitation.)